# UPDATE one table column based on another table's column

Tags: mysql

In one table I have fields

```
  cat_id, cat_name
```

the table I need to update has several columns but I only want to update one based on the info in the new one.

```
 category
```

I would like to update the category  field to the cat_id of the corresponding name.

in other word

```
 IF 
 cat_id='66' and cat_name='STACKOVER'
 and
 category='STACKOVER'
```

The result should be

```
 category='66'
```

I'm not sure where to start..

Comment: Useful terms to Google for: http://www.google.com/search?q=multiple-table+update+mysql

Comment: that's pretty good help.  it is what you asked for - a start.

Comment: ha, google brought me here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood you,

`UPDATE new_category,category SET new_category.category=category.cat_id WHERE new_category.category=category.cat_name`

should do the job and lead you toward understanding multi-table updates.

Comment: Thank you Dvir. That makes total sense. I'll get the hang of this sooner or later. :)